# Magento Minicart not clear after delete all product programatically

Tags: magento-2.1, mini-cart

I have customized mini-cart. and place one new button Clear shopping cart. it's work fine. all item are deleted successfully. but mini cart total not updated in Magento 2. total updated only by one item.

check snap.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUvWY.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the mini-cart in you need to create a `sections.xml` in your module `etc/frontend` directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="checkout/cart/add">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Just replace `checkout/cart/add` with your `modulename/controller/actionname` and clear your webshop cache. You can also find the same thing in `magento-checkout` module from below path,

`app\code\Magento\Checkout\etc\frontend\sections.xml`

Magento does this job from below path (Just for debugging purpose),

`Magento\Customer\view\frontend\web\js\customer-data.js`

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, xhr, settings) {
    var sections,
        redirects;

    if (settings.type.match(/post|put|delete/i)) {
        sections = sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url);

        if (sections) {
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            redirects = ['redirect', 'backUrl'];

            if (_.isObject(xhr.responseJSON) && !_.isEmpty(_.pick(xhr.responseJSON, redirects))) { //eslint-disable-line
                return;
            }
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        }
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can also do by adding just piece of javascript code on your `AJAX` (I am assuming you are doing this operation by AJAX)

```
require([
           'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            var sections = ['cart'];
            customerData.invalidate(sections);
            customerData.reload(sections, true);
        });
```

Comment: nice answer bro...

Comment: i have try this but it update only for 1 item

Comment: @keyur Shah can you please help me in this question, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279346/how-to-clear-mini-cart-when-switching-between-stores-in-magento-2-3

Comment: what is this section.xml used for,

Comment: @AjayPatel did you get the solution. i am facing same issue

Comment: @Arjun i am using ajax to update the minicart block.

Comment: So second solution worked for you

Comment: Can you guide me on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316098/magento2-mini-cart-counter-not-getting-updated/316099?noredirect=1#comment453389_316099