# Magento2 mini cart counter not getting updated

Tags: magento2

Magento2 I am programmatiacally removing cart items.

```
$quoteItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
            foreach($quoteItems as $item)
            {
                $cart->removeItem($item->getId())->save(); 
            }
```

My issue is **mini cart counter is not getting updated**

It just gets reduced by 1. Lets say if I have 3 items it will get reduced by 1 & change to 2.

I have already tried

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="inquiry/index/save">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

And this

```
var sections = ['cart'];
customerData.reload(sections, true);
```

Comment: after page Refresh count work ?

Comment: try this link for update count  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/315972/82670

Comment: Please check this one https://prnt.sc/t8dhng

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Update-Minicart-after-add-product-in-cart-programmatically/td-p/24759

Comment: Not working @PushpendraSingh

Comment: please update me @Arjun

Comment: @Msquare I tried the solution but not working

Comment: It just gets reduce by 1

Comment: please check my answer and update me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Try this code**

```
$quoteItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($quoteItems as $item)
    {
        $cart->removeItem($item->getId()); 
    }

    $cart->save();
    
    //or use this 
    //$cart->save()->getQuote()->collectTotals()
```